# PL/SQL regex check

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have following regex for C#. It checks for 3 capital letters followed by 3 digits.

```
string reg = @"^[A-Z]{3}\d{3}";
```

Is it possible to write same kind of regex for PL/SQL? I am new to this.

Example valid text:

```
ABS123
AHS243
OPS234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been SQL support for regular expressions since Oracle 10g. Not sure how you want to use it, but perhaps you need something like this?

```
where regexp_like(your_column, '^[A-Z]{3}\d{3}')
```

There is pretty good support for Posix regular expressions. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_posix.htm#SQLRF020).

Answer (score -1):

Oracle and C# regular expression are same.